# How do you destroy an Angular 2 component without a ComponentFactory?

Tags: angular

When creating components dynamically through a ComponentFactory the ComponentRef that's returned provides a [destroy](https://angular.io/api/core/ComponentRef#destroy) method which works perfectly for what I'd like to accomplish.  With that in mind, it looks like all I need to do is a get a ComponentRef for a statically created component and then use its destroy function (which [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676997/angular-2-destroy-child-component) states), but when I try this I get an error saying that "destroy is not a function" even though I do get an object back.

Here's the syntax I'm using for ViewChild:

```
@ViewChild(MyComponent) myComponentRef: ComponentRef<MyComponent>;
```

And my "destroy" call:

```
private destroy() {
    this.myComponentRef.destroy();
}
```

Which is triggered here:

```
<button (click)="destroy()">Destroy</button>
```

Calling this "destroy" method works for components that I create dynamically, but not statically.

Edit:  <strike>So it seems like this does partially remove the component, but not from the DOM, which is not the same behavior that occurs when calling "destroy" on a dynamically created component.  Additionally, my click event function still fires when I click on a component that I've tried to destroy.</strike>

Edit 2:  I updated my ViewChild syntax to explicitly read for a ComponentRef and I get "undefined" back:

```
@ViewChild(MyComponent, {read: ComponentRef}) myComponentRef: ComponentRef<MyComponent>;
```

If that returns "undefined" then I'm guessing this may not be possible.

Comment: can u use *ngIf directive to dynamically remove the component?

Comment: Here's the Angular component lifecycle hooks page https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks @badger2013 What resources have you used to find documentation on ComponentFactory? https://medium.com/@Carmichaelize/angular-2-component-factory-resolver-395acb7c2129 - that was a new one on me.

Comment: Make use of https://angular.io/api/core/OnDestroy

Answer (score 0):

You can add a *ngIf in the container of your component and in a base to a condition (ngif) perform the destruction and creation of the child element. Example:

In the view:

```
<div *ngIf="destroy">
    <component-child></component-child>
</div>
<button (click)="destroyFunction()">Click to Destroy</button>
```

In the component parent class:

```
//Declare the view child
@ViewChild(componentChild) componentChild: componentChild;

//Declare the destroy variable
destroy:boolean;

//Add a function to change the value of destroy (boolean)
public destroyFunction(){
    this.destroy = false;
}
```

Performing these steps you can perform the destruction of the child element. I hope it works for you effectively

Comment: I added *ngIf, instead of a property I created a method and my ngIf is on my component tag instead of the div. my components are in mat-tabs. when switching tab, I am setting ngIf accordingly via my function. but when coming back to the tab, I can see the old results. It seems like components are not destroyed this way.