# Destroy all component at an auth gurd function if happens token was aliving

Tags: angular, typescript

## Angular onDestroy detected issue

As you know destory event isn't detected at the following cases

- enter key down at URL bar
- key down F5 key

## Way to check the following case actually Token is alive

So I tried to check existing token the after above action. And I caught AppComponet class instance from ActivatedRoute. Token is saved into LocalStorage fast of all, so available to get manage data using the token. And return current page but Angular created new the component. I should destory all components before return current page but I'm not sure the way to that.
Let me know the way if you know.

```
  async canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {

      // token check
      let result = this.authFactiry.CheckToken();
      if (result) {

        // get manage data for user
        result = await this.authFactiry.GetData();
      }

      if (result) { 
        this.destoryComponents(); // <- I would like to know this detail
        return result;
      }

      const comp = this.route.Component; // this is AppComponent

      // if check error navigate to login page
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
      return result;
  }
```

Comment: In this case, ActivatedRoute.routeConfig is null, you know

Comment: when you refresh it will destroy all the components ? what do you mean you want to destroy them ?

Comment: check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56340306/angular-component-are-not-getting-destroyed
It is not perfect to complete this angular issue. Angular core create new Component for current Page after returned true from auth guard function.

Comment: can you share you code at github?

Comment: You don't need debug this code if you are not sure the matter

Comment: In this case, if returned false instead of true, main content of current page was gone.

Comment: I confirmed created AppComponent as new after returned true. I understood Angular core renew services...

Comment: what you have to destroy? Angular is a single page application so when you type an URL or refresh the page with F5 you're actually destroy the components and reload everything, when you use routingin angular you're not loading a new page even though you see a different URL

Comment: In our developing, Dom is not destoyed at pushed F5 or Enter
After that Angular makes new app modules, lost control previous
such like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56340306/angular-component-are-not-getting-destroyed
So it is better we use 2 domains, one is for login other one is for main